# How to setup re-usable non-entry specific data in Craft?

Tags: craft3

The current CMS I use allows me to create data tables with list data that I can then re-use across different page-types throughout the sites that I build.

The only way I can see to make use of concept in a similar way without developing a custom plugin in Craft is to create specific entry types with tables to input and retrieve data from.

Does anyone have any advice on what the best practice would be with Craft with regards to larger sets of table data?

Comment: You could use super table and make a channel of list tables and then associate those table entries to page entries via an entry field